# How to have multiple image in left right, up?

Tags: captions, subfloats, subcaption

Basically I want to have an Figure like below:

[image]

However, I am able to put left right, how to add an Up?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=0.5in]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}


\begin{figure}[ht]
\begin{subfigure}{.5\textwidth}
  \centering
  % include first image
  \includegraphics[width=.5\linewidth]{image_file_name}  
  \caption{Put your sub-caption here}
  \label{fig:sub-first}
\end{subfigure}
\begin{subfigure}{.5\textwidth}
  \centering
  % include second image
  \includegraphics[width=.5\linewidth]{image_file_name}  
  \caption{Put your sub-caption here}
  \label{fig:sub-second}
\end{subfigure}
\caption{Put your caption here}
\label{fig:fig}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

My current output:

[image]

Comment: Just add a blank line or `\par` after the first subfigure, and perhaps `\hfil` or  `\hfill` between the bottom subfigures.

Comment: @John Kormylo, if you an provide a simple MWE will be great.

Answer (score 2):

Just add the third image...
Or do i mis something?

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=0.5in]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}


    \begin{figure}[ht]
        \begin{subfigure}{\textwidth}
            \centering
            % include first image
            \includegraphics[width=.25\linewidth]{example-image-a}  
            \caption{Put your sub-captionA here}
            \label{fig:sub-firstA}
        \end{subfigure}
        \begin{subfigure}{.5\textwidth}
            \centering
            % include first image
            \includegraphics[width=.5\linewidth]{example-image-b}  
            \caption{Put your sub-captionB here}
            \label{fig:sub-first}
        \end{subfigure}
        \begin{subfigure}{.5\textwidth}
            \centering
            % include second image
            \includegraphics[width=.5\linewidth]{example-image-c}  
            \caption{Put your sub-captionC here}
            \label{fig:sub-second}
        \end{subfigure}
        \caption{Put your caption here}
        \label{fig:fig}
    \end{figure}

\end{document}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**UPDATE**
With less space in between the images

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=0.5in]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}


    \begin{figure}[ht]
        \begin{subfigure}{\textwidth}
            \centering
            % include first image
            \includegraphics[width=.45\linewidth]{example-image-a}   % this width should be half of the width of the other two images
            \caption{Put your sub-captionA here}
            \label{fig:sub-firstA}
        \end{subfigure}
        \begin{subfigure}{.5\textwidth} % this sets the figure to be max half the width of the page
            \centering
            % include first image
            \includegraphics[width=.9\linewidth]{example-image-b}  % this sets the image to fill 90% of the available space -> 45% of the line width in total. 
            \caption{Put your sub-captionB here}
            \label{fig:sub-first}
        \end{subfigure}
        \begin{subfigure}{.5\textwidth}
            \centering
            % include second image
            \includegraphics[width=.9\linewidth]{example-image-c}  
            \caption{Put your sub-captionC here}
            \label{fig:sub-second}
        \end{subfigure}
        \caption{Put your caption here}
        \label{fig:fig}
    \end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: could you explain how to adjust the size of the image? And also, there is a big gap between B and C.

Comment: See my update with comments in code. You set the width of the image in the figure itself. Note that A can use the whole textwidth, B and C only half, so the size of A has to be half of that of B/C to be similar.

Answer (score 0):

In this example I reduced the width of the subfigure/caption to the width of the image.  Note that placing `\hfil` between the two lower subfigures expands to the same gap as `\centering`, while `\hfill` would push the subfigures all the way to the edges.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=0.5in,showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[ht]
\centering
\begin{subfigure}{.45\textwidth}
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}  
  \caption{Put your sub-caption here}
  \label{fig:sub-first}
\end{subfigure}% ending a line with a brace adds a space
\vspace{\floatsep}% space added between consecutive floats

\begin{subfigure}{.45\textwidth}
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-b}  
  \caption{Put your sub-caption here}
  \label{fig:sub-secon}
\end{subfigure}\hfil
\begin{subfigure}{.45\textwidth}
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-c}  
  \caption{Put your sub-caption here}
  \label{fig:sub-third}
\end{subfigure}
\caption{Put your caption here}
\label{fig:fig}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image: demo]

Comment: thanks. Would you able to increase the image size too?